# What are the good things about dividing groups in addressable?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXjQb.png)

Currently, I am using the Unity 2021.3.15f version.
I often use the Unity Addressable package.
I am using the Addressable package version 1.19.19.
However, I don't know much about the Addressable package.
I am currently using only one default group.
There are groups in the Addressable, so what's good about dividing them?
Besides, what should I do with the build if I divide the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about reading the following blog? It may answer some of your questions.

Tales from the optimization trenches: Saving memory with Addressables
https://blog.unity.com/en/technology/tales-from-the-optimization-trenches-saving-memory-with-addressables

> what should I do with the build if I divide the group?

There is no difference in the [build method](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.19/manual/Builds.html#build-commands). They build together.